# My hard drive has been running for 26 billion years?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smart

I have a Ubuntu server I'm loading up with (used, pulled from other systems) hard drives for storing downloaded files.  I've been using smartctl to test each drive before I start using it.

One of the drives looks like it may be ok, or may be messed up.  It only has 1 reallocated sector, which is probably acceptable for files I can afford to lose, as long as it doesn't increase.

The weird thing is that I get some seemingly random data from the SMART output, particularly for Head_Flying_Hours:

`240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       231966888734858`

That's 26 **billion** years.  That can't be right!  And it's increasing quickly...20 minutes later it read 170,192,374,116,491 hours - 19,428,353,209 years!

The other data from SMART stays stable and at first glance looks reasonable for a somewhat older drive.

Is this a firmware or smartctl bug that I can ignore, or a sign that this disk has some serious issues? If money werent an issue I would just trash it, but if its otherwise ok it would be fine for storing files I can afford to lose.

Other drives in the system all seem to report normal smart data.  I havent tried putting it in a windows system to test yet.

### Full smartctl output

```
root@server:/mnt# smartctl -a /dev/sdf
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-39-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.11
Device Model:     ST31500341AS
Serial Number:    9VS1KMRC
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 014916513
Firmware Version: CC1H
User Capacity:    1,500,301,910,016 bytes [1.50 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Thu Nov 13 18:22:24 2014 EST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  617) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 293) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x103f) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   120   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       240260056
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   100   095   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       86
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   084   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       246081153
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   049   049   000    Old_age   Always       -       45195
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       80
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       12885098499
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   048   048   000    Old_age   Always       -       52
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   068   049   045    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 23/32)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   032   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (0 23 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   048   018   000    Old_age   Always       -       240260056
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       231966888734858
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2915905399
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1182879756

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     44530         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     33993         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33969         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33945         -
# 5  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     33928         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33921         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33897         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33873         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33849         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33825         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33801         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33777         -
#13  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     33759         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33753         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33729         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33705         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33681         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33657         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33633         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33609         -
#21  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     33591         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Time to junk that piece of hardware old man..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that you installed newer firmware CC1H (14-15 series uses it by default) which uses `msec24hour32` format for that attribute. Try `smartctl -v 240,msec24hour32`.

Answer (score 1):

The drive is definitely old but looks fine from the limited information you have presented.... You reallocated sector count is only 1 which doesn't appear to be a dying disk.  power up hours is 45195 is what I would use here (which is about 5.2 years).

BTW, 1.5 TB disks are not really all that expensive these days (easily < $100).

Normally, I'd get a new disk and not worry about things.

Comment: Easily < $100 heck;  they are less then $50 in most cases.  Considering < $150 are 3TB+ drives